# What is the line marked at the first slip for the spinner?

Tags: cricket

What is the line marked at the first slip for the spinner? There is a light green grass at the end of pitch where the first slip for spin bowler stands or an umpire stands.I want to know why that grass is light coloured near the pitch and what is that line marked with light green color at the end of the pitch?

You can see the image below

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Could you add a photo showing what you're taking about?

Comment: I can't make out which line you're referring to - could you add an arrow to the photo to make it clearer please?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the arrows supplied, that isn't a line as such - it's the edge of the square.

The square is the area of the playing surface that's prepared for batting, and will usually be a different colour, due to increased levels of care, particularly watering.